# Edit post in modal with Firebase ngRoute issues

Tags: firebase, ngroute

Hi I have been looking for a solution everywhere but I am confused by the variation of answers to the issue I am having.

I have a click button inside an ng-repeat that launches a bootstrap modal. The ng-repeat is a list of posts in a firebase datasource. I want to do the typical thing of launching the modal form with the given post's editable contents.

Modal:

````

```
 <!--bootstrap modal-->
                <div class="modal fade" id="editModal"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <form role="form">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Title:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" ng-model="postToUpdate.title">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Post:</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text" ng-model="postToUpdate.Body"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Button:
                      EDIT

MY CONTROLLER

```
app.controller('postController', function($scope, $timeout, $modal,$firebaseArray, $firebaseObject, $routeParams, $log) {
```

EDIT FUNCTION:
  //EDIT Post

```
$scope.editPost = function(id) {
    console.log(id);
    var id = $routeParams.id;
    var ref = new Firebase("https://FIREBASESOURCE.firebaseio.com/Posts/" + id);

    var obj = $firebaseObject(ref);


     $scope.postToUpdate = obj;

    $('#editModal').modal();      // triggers the modal pop up
}
```

I had some issues with migrating some of the code i.e. not using $firebase and $asObject(), which I updated but the ID's are not being retrieved and modal launches empty. I then added the $routeParams to my function and  ngRoute to my app `var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute', 'firebase']);` yet I am still getting  the `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)`

Can Firebase work with ngRoute?

Answer (score 0):

After reading a lot about this I found that the ID needs to be referred via `var id = ref.key();` so this now works.

```
$scope.editPost = function(id) {

    var ref = new Firebase("https://FIREBASESOURCE.firebaseio.com/Posts/" + id);
    var id = ref.key();

     var syncObject = $firebaseObject(ref);
    $scope.postToUpdate = syncObject;
      console.log($scope.postToUpdate.$id);
     // triggers the modal pop up
    $('#editModal').modal();
}
```